How connect React to MQTT over WSS
I am trying to connect to the MQTT Broker using MQTT.js in my React application, but I am getting an error with the WSS protocol.
First, my mosquitto.conf file:
# mosquitto.conf

pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

listener 3940
protocol mqtt

listener 39393
protocol websockets

listener 3941
protocol mqtt
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/broker.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/broker.key

listener 3942
protocol websockets
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/broker.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/broker.key

And the code block in my React application:
// some.jsx

useEffect(() => {
        let reconnectAttempts = 0;
        try {
            if (user && !client) {
                const host = "ws://my.domain.io:39393"
                // const host = "wss://my.domain.io:3942
                const options = {
                    keepalive: 60,
                    clientId: `${user.username}_${user.id}_${user.tenant}_${Date.now()}`,
                    username: "username",
                    password: "password",
                    clean: true,
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                };
                const mqttClient = mqtt.connect(host, options);
                setClient(mqttClient);
                console.log("client: ", mqttClient);

                mqttClient.on("connect", () => {
                    console.log("Connected to MQTT broker");
                    setIsConnected(true);
                    setIsReconnecting(false);
                    setIsDisconnected(false);
                    reconnectAttempts = 0;
                });
                
                mqttClient.on("disconnect", () => {
                    console.log("Disconnected to MQTT broker");
                    setIsConnected(false);
                    setIsDisconnected(true);
                });
                
                mqttClient.on("close", (err) => {
                    console.log("Closed connection to MQTT broker", err);
                });

                mqttClient.on("reconnect", () => {
                    reconnectAttempts++;
                    setIsReconnecting(true);

                    if (reconnectAttempts > 5) {
                        mqttClient.end();
                        console.log("Reconnect attempts exceeded. Closing connection to MQTT broker");
                        setIsConnected(false);
                        setIsDisconnected(true);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log("Reconnecting to MQTT broker", reconnectAttempts);
                });
                
                mqttClient.on("error", (err) => {
                    console.log("Error from MQTT broker", err); 
                });
            }   
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error connecting to MQTT broker", error);
        }

        return () => {
            if (client) {
                console.log("MQTT Hook cleanup")
                client.end();
                setClient(null);
            }
        }
    }, [user, client]);

I can connect to the host mqtts://my.domain.io:3941 on my local device, but I cannot connect to the host wss://my.domain.io:3942 in the production environment because I need to connect via HTTPS. Additionally, I can connect to wss://my.domain.io:3942 and perform pub/sub operations without any issues using Python, MQTT Box, and MQTT Explorer.
SS from MQTT Box:

UPDATE:
# some.py
    def connect(self):
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        
        self.client.tls_set(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
        
        self.client.username_pw_set(self.username, self.password)
        
        self.client.connect(self.broker, self.port, keepalive=10)
        self.client.loop_start()

My Mosquitto logs are as follows. My backend application running in the local environment can connect to the port 3941 without a certificate, while my React application can only connect to the port 39393 without a certificate.

When my React application in the production environment tries to connect to port 39393, my console shows:

When it tries to connect to port 3942, my console shows:

Lastly, even though my React application is set to either port 39393 or 3942 in the production environment, no data appears in my Mosquitto logs.
So I want connect React to MQTT over WSS in my production server.

"I cannot connect" is not really enough detail to enable us to help. Please tell us what happens when you try to connect (do you get an error, what is shown in the browser console/dev tools network tab, is there anything in Mosquitto log etc). A MRE would also help as, it's not really clear where your code example fits into the wider app (this tutorial might help).

@Brits you are right my bad sorry, I updated my post.

A page served via HTTPS will not be able to connect to ws (only wss, the browser prevents a secure page from making insecure connections). The wss connection is failing, but you have not included the reason for this in your log screenshot (and this references a subscription that is not shown in your code). Please focus your question on one server or the other (local vs production); otherwise things get confusing (your Mosquitto log does not match up with the wss browser screenshot).

@Brits When I tried to connect to WSS via https, I couldn't connect and Mosquitto couldn't log it

We can see that the connection fails from your screenshot, but cannot see the reason because you did not expand any if those lines.

@Brits There was nothing descriptive, just a few package names.

Please humour me (the stack trace often helps trace the issue); the info from the network tab may also be useful (to see what the response to the wss request is). In terms of the mosquitto logs I'm only interested in the attempt to connect via wss (nothing else will work from the browser where the page was served over https). Note that the cafile in the mosquitto config is only needed when using client certificates (and these are not really usable within  browser).

@Brits I don't know, in my browser console I only see package names, and on the Mosquitto side, there were no browser-side logs for wss, so my brain is really fried.

OK - as you have accepted an answer this question will be considered resolved...

I had an issue where I couldn't connect to a secure MQTT broker at wss://dash.meetlarry.io:3942 over HTTPS while on a React Linux server. The steps I followed to solve this issue are as follows:

First, I modified the Nginx configuration files to include the MQTT
configuration, as the React server already had configurations for
the certificates:
# React App Server
server {
    server_name my.domain.io;

    root /var/www/html/app/build;
    index index.html;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.io/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /mqtt {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:39393;  # Mosquitto WebSocket port
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for React App
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.io;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


Then, I updated the code within React as follows:
const options = {
    host: "my.domain.io", // current server name with certificate
    port: 443, // port listened by nginx
    path: '/mqtt', // location assigned in nginx
    protocol: 'wss', // protocol
    keepalive: 60,
    clientId: `${user.username}_${user.id}_${user.tenant}_${Date.now()}`,
    username: "username",
    password: "password",
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
const mqttClient = mqtt.connect(options);
setClient(mqttClient);


Next, I updated the MQTT configurations on the DRF side:
class MQTTClient:
    def __init__(self, broker, port, username, password):
        self.broker = broker
        self.port = port
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        client_id = f"larry_hotline-{random.randint(0, 1000)}"
        self.client = mqtt.Client(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION2, client_id, transport="websockets")

    def connect(self):
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect

        self.client.tls_set(cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)

        self.client.username_pw_set(self.username, self.password)

        self.client.connect(self.broker, self.port, keepalive=10)
        self.client.loop_start()


I ran my Django application on the 3942 WebSocket port to ensure messages are transmitted, and this solved the strange issue.


The reason I resorted to this solution is that I tried to certificate the IP address of my MQTT broker and connect by entering this IP address instead of the domain name through MQTT.js, but both attempts failed. I would have preferred to create a specific certificate for the MQTT broker and connect with MQTT.js directly. If anyone has managed to connect in this way before, I would be very happy if they could explain this method to me as well :)
